It is possible to use the History state in Events?
Im using a statechart to reproduce the pass throug the life phases (Baby, Child, Fertil and Elders). These states are inside a composite state. This composite state has two internal transitions: emigration and death. Both transitions uses messages triggered by rates.
Im trying to know the last simple state visited by the agent when receive the message for death or even emigrate.
Im trying to use deep history state, inside the composite state.
HistoryState1 (HS1) for the last visited simple state by agents who receive the death message and HistoryState2 (HS2) for the last visited simple state by agents who receive the emigrate message.
Both, HS1 and HS2 are linked to simple states outside from the composite state (from Deaths to HistoryState1 and Emigrants to HistoryState2), needing to know exactly the last visited state name. Not sure if these two last links are needed or even OK.
I dont know how to get exactly the last visited state name visited by the agent when he receive the message.
I want to use the last state simple name visited by the agent in a Event. Dont know how to proceed.

If you could provide a picture of the statechart it would be easier to understand what you have and what you need. Either way, if the existing functions do not suit you, you can always se a variable when entering a state so you can control the granularity you need

How can a variable get the last agent active state?

I used a variable to get the state's name at every state Entry action. So the variable always has the active state. Then I used the variable value in the message transition Action to do what I want it. Thank you @Enrico

Glad to help! :) The idea I was proposing was exactly that - on every state entry the variable would be set to the appropriate value
